# Why do I get "No assembly descriptors found." error while building this project?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, kotlin, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a little [project](https://bitbucket.org/altruix/alma-econsim/src) written in Kotlin. When I run `clean compile assembly:single install`, I get following error message:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single 
(default-cli) on project alma-econsim: Error reading assemblies: No assembly 
descriptors found. -> [Help 1]
```

My `jar-with-dependencies.xml` is located in [src/main/assembly](https://bitbucket.org/altruix/alma-econsim/src/4c06fceb8e2e1ec2e4ebb78d4d481eed0619b4a1/src/main/assembly/jar-with-dependencies.xml?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) and referenced in [pom.xml](https://bitbucket.org/altruix/alma-econsim/src/d747ed949f232d4219170141503a7b8d1615a8dd/pom.xml?fileviewer=file-view-default) like this:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>assembly</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/jar-with-dependencies.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But I still get the error. How can I correct my project in order to be able to package it as jar with dependencies?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First use an uptodate version of [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) and not an ancient version...Furthermore you should call it via `mvn clean package` cause you bound the maven-assembly-plugin to the `package` life cycle phase...if you try to do `mvn ... assembly:single` you are not calling the life cycle...Apart from that you would like to use `jar-with-dependencies` descriptor than you should do that like this:

```xml
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <!-- NOTE: We don't need a groupId specification because the group is
             org.apache.maven.plugins ...which is assumed by default.
         -->
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        [...]
</project>
```

Apart from that if you call Maven like this:

```
mvn clean compile assembly:single install
```

Than you calling the compile phase double, cause just simply a:

```
mvn clean install
```

is sufficient. I can recommend to read the [build life doc.](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

Comment: This is super helpful. Thank you.